# Normal subgroups of the group of invertible $2×2$ upper triangular matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of all invertible $2×2$ upper triangular matrices (under matrix multiplication). Pick out the normal subgroups of $G$ from the following:
(a) $H=\{A\in G:a_{12}=0\}$;
(b) $H=\{A\in G:a_{11}=1\}$;
(c) $H=\{A\in G:a_{11}=a_{22}\}$.

---

After calculation I get only (b) is right. Am I correct?

Comment: $b,c$ are correct

Answer (score 7):

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b_{11} &b_{12}\\
 0 & b_{22}
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_{11} &a_{12}\\
 0 & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 b_{11} &b_{12}\\
 0 & b_{22}
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_{11} &\frac{b_{22} a_{12}+a_{11} b_{12}-a_{22} b_{12}}{b_{11}} \\
 0 & a_{22}
\end{array}
\right)$$

You can see that $a_{11}=a_{22}$ works, as well as $a_{11}=1$.  However you can still have $a_{12}=0$ and a nonzero $_{12}$ entry on the RHS.

Comment: So all three, a) b) and c) options work right?